# What are the recommended DNS client settings for AD DCs?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Given the following scenario: 2 W2k8 DCs, each in a different site with own subnet. What are the DNS client settings I should use? The best practice analyser says the the DC should not have itself as first DNS server, but I have also read that the DCs should use the same DNS server as primary server. Obviously, I cannot implement both recommendations at the same time with 2 DCs, so an external DNS server would be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I've taken the class, but the setup I've used for years is this.  I'm assuming you are using the DCs as DNS servers for client machines.

- Each DC's network settings point to itself ("real" IP address in 2k, 127.0.0.1 in > 2k3)
- Each DC's DNS resolver settings point to a close-by DNS server, e.g. your ISP's.
- AD will take care of replicating internal domain addresses among each DC.  Let someone else take care of replicating the resolver data.

Comment: There seems to be some dispute about wether using 127.0.0.1 or the real IP. But the thing that is interesting for me is the order of DNS servers on the DCs: always the same or vice versa (if having two). And what to do when I have more than two DCs?